# Express Typescript Definition Use Router Middleware Broke?

Tags: node.js, express

Just installed typescript definition for `express` and associated typescript dependencies `express-serve-static-core` and `serve-static` such that my `typings.json` contains

```
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160708185218",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#4.0.0+20160715232503",
    "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#0.0.0+20160606155157"
```

However, now attempting to add a router as middleware using `use`, i.e.,

```
var server = express();
server.use('/app', express.Router());
```

is giving me a `Argument types do not match` intellisense error in WebStorm. There appears now only to be a single definition of `use` on the `express-serve-static-core` type definition. Looking at a previous installation, I was using the following typescript definition version

```
"express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#0.0.0+20160701212727"
```

without any problems. Firstly, there appears to be a massive version jump here within the space of a week, i.e., `0.0.0+20160701212727` to `4.0.0+20160715232503`. Is this really correct? Have I missed something?